# How to cause side effects to an instance variable in python?

Tags: python, recursion, reference

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree in python to practice recursion skills, but my `head` variable isn't updating on the first call to `add()`. It continues to stay at a null value even though it should be updated on the first call as it is the `currentNode`. What am I doing wrong?

```py
class BinarySearchTree:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.Right = None
            self.Left = None

    head = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, newNode):
        self.__addrecursive(self.head, newNode)

    def __addrecursive(self, currentNode, valueToAdd):
        if currentNode is None:
            currentNode = self.Node(valueToAdd)
            return currentNode
        elif valueToAdd < currentNode.data:
            return self.__addrecursive(self, currentNode.Left, valueToAdd)
        else:
            return self.__addrecursive(self, currentNode.Right, valueToAdd)
```

```py
import BinarySearchTree as treelib

tree = treelib.BinarySearchTree()
tree.add("Apple")
print(tree.head) #Head should contain "Apple" but is intead None
```

Comment: `currentNode = self.Node(valueToAdd)` assigns to a **local variable** called `currentNode`, that doesn't affect `self.head`.

Comment: right, if you store value in self.head, it exists withing class sl first, remove static value head  = None, then remove currentNode and repalce currentNode  on self.head

Answer (score 1):

I have made a few changes to your code.

1. removed the `head = None` which is never used
2. addded `self.head =`  inside the add function becaues previously __addrecursive was returning a node but it wasn't being assigned to anything
3. in the case where currentNode is None just return the node directly rather than assigning to currentNode
4. remove the self argument to each of the recursive calls
5. assign the return value of the recursive call to the left or right side of the currentNode
6. return the currentNode at the end which bring everything back up to the top level and be returned and assigned to self.head

```py
class BinarySearchTree:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.Right = None
            self.Left = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, newNode):
        self.head = self.__addrecursive(self.head, newNode)

    def __addrecursive(self, currentNode, valueToAdd):
        if currentNode is None:
            return self.Node(valueToAdd)
        elif valueToAdd < currentNode.data:
            currentNode.Left = self.__addrecursive(currentNode.Left, valueToAdd)
        else:
            currentNode.Right = self.__addrecursive(currentNode.Right, valueToAdd)
        return currentNode
```

I don't really know about binary trees so I could be wrong because I just copied some code from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/